# Android - failed to open zip archive

Tags: android

I am downloading apk file from web and storing him into Context.getCacheDir(). I am downloading file by HttpURLConnection - I am not asking actually on the code (it is fully working), so I am not posting it here. I successfully initiate download. File is downloaded into cache and then is prompted installation - but system cannot open my APK and writes error of analysis.

Hence problem is as follows:

```
03-31 16:48:43.740: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.android.packageinstaller for activity com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: pid=620 uid=10026 gids={}
03-31 16:48:44.749: WARN/zipro(620): Unable to open zip '/data/data/com.my.app/cache/myApp.apk': Permission denied
03-31 16:48:44.749: DEBUG/asset(620): failed to open Zip archive '/data/data/com.my.app/cache/myApp.apk'
03-31 16:48:44.930: WARN/PackageParser(620): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/data/com.my.app/cache/myApp.apk
03-31 16:48:44.930: WARN/PackageParser(620): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
```

Problem is - I don't have permission to access programaticaly /cache. Is there any way how to solve it? I don't want to use external storage as a download directory (installation process works when I download file to external storage), cache is great because the file won't be accessible for general user from file manager and that's what I want. Thanks for your thoughts.

This problem has been for me unsolvable for over a month now...

**Edit:** Still no solution, I am trying to think that I found 1st thing, that is not possible with Android

**Edit2:** I must have been looking bad - my downloaded apk is present in cache... There is still no permission to allow install from that dir?

Comment: have you tried to use the `openFileOutput()`....if not, try it with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

Comment: Hi did you find the solution to above problem. I am in similar fix now.

Comment: I've seen `WORLD_WRITABLE` suggested in pretty much every answer in this comment. DO **NOT** DO THAT for other than a test that permissions are the problem.

Answer (score 6):

chmod 666 on the downloaded apk file before you install it in your code

more detail :

```
path = your_apk_file_path_in_cache_dir;
permission="666";

try {
    String command = "chmod " + permission + " " + path;
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec(command);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. After running that command the package installer can open the downloaded file.

Comment: I would use `chmod 644` instead as that is the permission set for `/system` apps. Not sure why you would want a `chmod 666` allowing other programs write permission. You could also install it and do this through `adb` and then restart.

Answer (score 3):

This is may help you:

```
FileOutputStream fOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(
    fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see what's happening..

The cache dir is a cache managed by Android, which means it can be cleaned as soon as the internal memory starts to run low.

AND if your application is taking too much space on a cache (what a APK is probably doing) when your application gets paused/stoped Android may clean your cache directory.

To test it this is the case, do everything as you did and when the installation process starts just open the DDMS and see if your file still in the cache.

If not, so android has cleaned the application's cache because it's not running anymore.

Try to user a different approach, instead of `context.getCacheDir()` try `context.getFilesDir()`

Comment: Hi, I am actually using Context.getCacheDir() and I can't see downloaded app in a cache in ADB... it looks like system is deleting it right after update...

Comment: Same for the context.getFilesDir() as for the getCacheDir() - no success

Comment: that's the problem...do you know the size of the apk? seems that it's too big to be stored in a internal storage...you will need to store it in the sdcard....install...then delete.

Comment: apk has 200 kB, cache must be definitely bigger. I am doing it as you have said, right now. I just thought, there must be better solution.

Comment: have you tried to use the openFileOutput()....if not, try it with MODE_WORLD_READABLE http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: can't tell at the moment, I have to significantly rework my download intent, because openFileOutput() is for storing files and I store them with BufferedInputStream and FileOutputStream