# Unable to debug via eclipse on phone with Jelly Bean

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a nexus S for sprint that I am using as a developer phone rooted to be running android 4.1.  Eclipse recognizes the phone, drivers, etc.  I can run "adb devices" and the phone id is displayed.  However, if I try to debug my app or any other imported project I get the following error:

Unable to open zip '/data/local/tmp/com.myapp.apk': Permission denied

(I would post the image but haven't posted here before)

If I manually transfer the .apk and install via Astro, everything runs perfectly.  I am considerably lost and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5503487/420015)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate of that to me. Have you tried installing your app to the Jelly Bean emulator? If that succeeds, then you have probably found a bug in your custom ROM.

Comment: I have similar issues.  What I see is that I cannot install my .apk because it is being created with permissions 600 instead of 666, which I believe it needs.  I also see my umask in adb is 077 which is potentially the cause of the issue, but I do not know how to get it set to the correct umask.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Let me know if it helped you, please.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking at this with a more recent version of the siyah kernal, if you don't wish to switch your kernel, you can use the "ExTweaks" app to change a settings under "MISC" called "ADB Binary Mode". I set this to "Development ADB"(was "Normal ADB") and can now successfully debug with eclipse! :D

Answer (score 3):

I have a custom ROM installed in my Galaxy S2. Searching by google i came to this post: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=29454043&postcount=203

The problem in my case was the kernel too (Siyah 3.5.2).

I installed another kernel for JB (http://developer.clockworkmod.com/downloads/51/3354/kernel-cm-10-20120801-i9100-signed.zip) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Basically

> /data/local

doesn't have the right permissions, so a simple:

```
adb shell
cd /data
chmod 777 local
```

should work. (Not sure if the new permissions are overbroad, but I'm not too worried)

Answer (score 0):

As per ekim's answer, I had the same issue, again, a Galaxy S2, etc. The latest version of Siyah fixes this problem and I can get back to running/debugging from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I updated SGS3 (I9300) to stock 4.1.1 ROM and I got the same problem.

After I unsuccessfully tried everything here and elsewhere suggested:

- clean all projects
- install via adb chmod 777 for /data/local/tmp (and direct subfolders)
- dancing the chicken dance (dunno who suggested that, but at least it
  produced some laughs ;)
- etc.

I installed SiyahKernel S3-v1.6.8 and the problem was gone.

After inspecting my UMASK, I saw it's now 0000 (and it was 0077 on stock kernel), so I concluded that **the wrong UMASK was the root cause of the error**.

Still, as can be seen from numerous other threads on this issue out there, it's very wrong for the stock kernel to cause that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to see if it's a permission issue:
adb install -s Your.apk

this will install on the SDcard rather than /data/local